# Wordpress custom form input check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've made a custom contact form in wordpress where the user has to fill in inputs step by step.

I've set fieldets for each step but some inputs are required and I want to check if the input value is empty and then let it stop. I've tried some things myself with an alert but whether it's empty or filled it gives me the alert anyway and after I click ok on the alert it still proceeds to the next step while I don't want that.

I hope someone can help me get on my way with this.

EDIT: I've added the jQuery with which I've tried it before.

The HTML:

```
<div class="msform">

    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul class="progressbar-form">
        <li class="active">Name &amp; Company Name</li>
        <li>E-mail &amp; Phone</li>
        <li>Amount &amp; Date</li>
        <li>Subject</li>
        <li>Comments &amp; Send</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Step 1</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill out your name and company name.</h3>
        [text* your-name class:required placeholder "Name*"] <!-- shortcode for wordpress form -->
        [text your-company placeholder "Company name"]
        <p style="color:#094076;">* = required</p>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button-form" value="Next" />    
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Step 2</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill out your e-mail and phonenumber.</h3>   
        [email* your-email class:required placeholder "E-mail*"]
        [tel* your-tel class:required placeholder "Phonenumber*"]
        <p style="color:#094076;">* = required</p>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-form" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button-form" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Step 3</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill out your amount and preferred date.</h3>    
        [number your-amount min:1 max:10 placeholder "Amount"]
        [date your-date min:2018-03-01 placeholder "Date"]
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-form" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button-form" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Step 4</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill out your subject.</h3>   
        [text* your-message class:required placeholder "Subject*"]
        <p style="color:#094076;">* = required</p>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-form" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button-form" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Questions or comments about this form?</h3>
        [textarea your-details placeholder "Questions / Comments"]
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-form" value="Previous" /> [submit class:next class:submit-form class:action-button-form "Verzenden"]
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Thank you!</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your message has been sent.</h3>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
//jQuery
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//jQuery Easing script
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//jQuery Form Script (WP syntax)
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

       // Disabling the enter-button to prevent premature sending
        jQuery('.msform').on('keyup keypress', function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });

    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; // Fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; // Fieldset styling
    var animating; // Prevent multi-click glitching

    jQuery(".next").click(function () { 
        if (animating) return false;
        if( !jQuery('input.required').val() ) {
           alert('warning');
           return false;
        }

        animating = true; 

        current_fs = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
        next_fs = jQuery(this).parent().parent().next();

        jQuery(".progressbar-form li").eq(jQuery("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        next_fs.show();

        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0 }, {
            step: function (now, mx) {
                //1. Scale current_fs to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. Let next_fs come in from right (50%)
                left = (now * 50) + "%";
                //3. Set opacity of next_fs to 1 when entering.
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')' });
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
            },
            duration: 800, 
            complete: function () {
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false; 
            },
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });       
    });


    jQuery(".previous").click(function () {
        if (animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent().parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().parent().prev();

        jQuery(".progressbar-form li").eq(jQuery("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        previous_fs.show();
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0 }, {
            step: function (now, mx) {    
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left });
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')', 'opacity': opacity });
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function () {
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

To prevent this post from getting any longer I've left out the CSS.

[Here's a fiddle even tho it doesnt work because its wordpress stuff](https://jsfiddle.net/us8ah8xz/1/)

Comment: I don't see any code/logic where you check the field if it is empty or not ? And I don't see a single javascript `alert()` code there

Comment: No sorry I got a little frustrated after a while so I deleted the whole check for input. I'll edit the post

Comment: I've added the jQuery code i used before.

Comment: Not sure about why it still proceed to next step, but one flaw i can see is that , when you are on Name step those other `required` fields on others next step are still empty right. and you are checking with `if( !jQuery('input.required').val() ) {` which doesn't mean that it will check the current step value. I'm still not sure what could be the cause but thats what i got after reading your codes for now.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't know how I could've watched over this. I can give the first fieldset a class to check and after check .addClass() to the next field, I think? Would still leave me with the alert and still proceed to next step

Comment: Yeah try to solve that first may be the other problem magically go away haha. Try console log the input value to see if it checking/getting properly.

Answer (score 0):

relatively new to StackOverflow but if I understood your question correctly you could maybe use something along the lines of:

```
if($('.input1').val()){
Your Code here
}
```

This basically checks if the input1 has content in, whether that be checkbox or text.

This could be what you're looking for, maybe not but hey ho worth a shot of helping :P

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your try but it's not quite what I was looking for. I found out that it checks all fieldsets which can be solved by giving classes. but i still dont know why after getting the alert it proceeds to the next step

Comment: Okay well sorry it wasn't much help, Do you keep the .val() as it is or have you added .val("")? If you don't add the "" it may be looking for any value instead of a blank value.

Comment: I did create a Ajax Register form which requires to be checked for missing values but I can't for the life of me see where I've done so :L I will keep checking and as soon as I find I will copy it into a new answer for something else for you to try.     You see I created it from scratch not through plugin/wordpress. I created all the securty checks myself and use $sanitizeTextField

Comment: Also if I may, I'd suggest adding in your document.ready(function(){ to add $ inside the functions param. Doing this allows you to change all the jQuery selectors before many of your lines to a $ sign. Just cleans up your code somewhat

Comment: Allright I might try the .val("") soon. And thanks alot for your time. Concerning the $; i used document.ready but wordpress doesnt recognize $ as function since it might conflict with other scripts or something. Is why they expect jQuery instead of $.

Comment: No problem my friend, anytime. But in terms of the $ you sure it's wordpress not recognising it? I'm doing some theme development atm so I'm not sure whether you're doing the same or using the inbuild editor (not adviced ) but like i say if you do jQuery(document).ready(function($){} It should recognise that as it's a global selector for Jquery. If you don't have the $ in the function that's when it doens't recognise it but I'll leave you to it :) Hope you find out the answer to your question. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: You're right @Sam Ryan. If i start with: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ` I can indeed use $ as function

Comment: Jobs a gooden then :) Like I say hope you find the answer you require but I guess theres a bit of help from me :D

Answer (score 0):

It checks all inputs with the class required, means also the ones outside that fieldset. So gave the fieldset a class and let it check within. Then after check give that class to the next fieldset.

Obvious but I've been blind.

Credits to @cjmling for letting me see what I couldn't